# i want to transmit data from avr to pc.whats wrong in below connection or code

Tags: serial-port, avr

connection:
USB to TTL interface modules four pins:
1)0v-volt of avr
2)vcc-5 volt avr
3)TXD-TX of avr
4)RXD-RX of avr
and the USB to TTL serial interface module connected to PC using USB to RS-232 convertor DB9 cable.

below is the code:

```
    #include<avr/io.h>

void UART_transmit(unsigned char data);

int main(void)

{

    unsigned char i,message[]="i love india\r\n";
    DDRD=0x00;
    PORTD=0xFF;
    UCSRA=0;
    UCSRB=1<<TXEN; // transmitter enable
    UCSRC=1<<URSEL | 1<<UCSZ1 | 1<<UCSZ0; // 8 data bit, a stop, none parity
    UBRRH=0;
        UBRRL=5; // for 9600 baud at 1MHz

        while(1)

        {

        for(i=0;message[i];i++)



     {

        UART_transmit(message[i]);

        }

        } // while(1) end

        } // main() end

void UART_transmit(unsigned char data)
{
  while(!(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));
  UDR=data;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect TXD  of the USB-to-TTL module to Rx of the avr (and RXD to Tx)?

Comment: yes i tried this also

Answer (score 0):

RX of each device must be connected to TX of the other, and vice versa, unless you are using a null modem cable, in which case your connections are correct.  You might try using a multimeter and google to determine if your connecting cable is straight or null-modem.

I also recommend that you revise your code as outlined in the manufacturer's application note AVR306: Using the AVR® UART in C.  This is the authoritative reference on setting up and using the UART on AVR microcontrollers.